# django crontab schedule not being executed

Tags: python, django, cron

Trying to run django crontab in docker-compose
when running the command manually using `python manage.py crontab run some-hash`, it works 
otherwite it's never executed, here's my compose

```
version: '3.8'
   
services:
    django:
        build: .
        container_name: django
        command: bash -c "service cron start && python manage.py crontab add && crontab -l && gunicorn -w 2 -b 0.0.0.0:8000 project.wsgi:application"
        restart: always
        env_file:
            - .env
        ports:
            - "8000:8000"
        volumes:
            - .:/code
```

it shows the command being added but it's never executed

settings.py:

```
CRONJOBS = [
    ('* * * * *', 'django.core.management.call_command', ['dumpdata_daily'], {})
]

CRONTAB_COMMAND_SUFFIX = '2>&1'
```

also added `django_crontab` to installed_apps

and cron is installed in Dockerfile using `apt-get`

what am I doing wrong?

----EDIT--- 
I was finally able to making it log errors by making `/var/log/cron.log` file. 
Logs says it can't access secret-key when running the command probably because it can't read environment variables from .env file, any ideas how to fix this?

Answer (score 1):

Solved it, cron starts in a fresh shell and reads environment variables from `/etc/default/locale`

just executed that command

`printenv > /etc/default/locale && service cron start && python manage.py crontab add`

and it worked like a charm

Comment: Thank you so much! I've looked everywhere for an answer to this problem. I have tried everything else for days, but this solved my problem.